# How to just get a list of command-line arguments in Crystal lang

Tags: command-line, crystal-lang

I'm a newbie in Crystal lang, and I just wanted to know how to get a list (array) of command-line arguments in Crystal. I am aware that there's `OptionParser`. But I just want to get a list of arguments users typed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. It's just as easy as this:

```
puts(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 4):

`ARGV` is a Top Level Constant that contains all command line arguments.

Documentation can be found here: https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.3.2/toplevel.html